# Reshape pandas dataframe which has dict as values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, reshape

I have a pandas dataframe which has dict as values. I would like to transform this dataframe into the format in expected result.

[image: image of the df i have]

and i want to split the columns into each keys of the dict.
For example for the first columns 'questionnaire', i want 'questionnaire.step', 'questionnaire.lastCompletedStep' and so on.

the issue here it's that json normalization doesn't works:

```
json_normalize(data=data)
```

someone know how to fix it?

Comment: The column questionnaire suggested doesn't have consistent data, it has None and empty values. What do you plan to do with them? json_normalize is to convert raw json data to pandas. As in the case of front, you can iterate through the rows, append them to a list and convert it to a json (ie you need consistent JSON format, no None's allowed) and use json_normalize to convert the data to a dataframe.

Comment: what is the desired output?  the nested dictionary items can be enumerated by walking down the tree through a recursive function.

Comment: the output expected is a dataframe with columns of all keys of ur dict in each columns. For example, for questionnaire i need to have 'questionnaire.step', 'questionnaire.lastCompletedStep' with value of the specifique keys. In case it's None, i also need theses columns with None values. And that is the big issue. Because i need theses columns for None values. So we have to tcheck another row which contain a dict (and not empty dict) to know wich columns i have to create.

Answer (score 1):

Is the column value in the format of type `string` ? If it is then you can try this.
I tried this on a dataframe and it worked. Iterate over each column values convert them from `str` to `dict` then iterate over those values create a new column with key value and assign the value to the column.

```
data  =  [str({"step": 7, "lastCompletedStep": 7})]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["questionaire"])
df
```

[image]

```
dataval = df.questionaire[0]
print(type(dataval))
```

[image]

```
result = eval(dataval)
print(result)
print(type(result))
```

[image]

```
for i,(k, v) in enumerate(result.items()):
df["questionaire"+"."+str(k)] = v
df
```

[image]

Comment: It's not the output expected! Actually i want to split the dict into a DataFrame which has columns ['questionnaire.step',  'questionnaire.lastCompletedStep',  ...] . The columns refer to keys of the dict which is on the value of the columns 'questionnaire'. But sometime it's None and sometime it's just a empty dict {}.  Is it  mutch explain?

Comment: So you want to use the key as a column name and then assign the respective value to the row ?

Comment: I guess my edit would be what you are expecting.

Comment: Yes, the output is good for 1 row which have a dict, but my dataframe have a lot of row with None value. So i need to check if the value it's a dict or a None. if it's None so i have to put None on all columne i create from 'questionnaire'. So for this row i need to have, 'None' on 'questionnaire.step' and 'questionnaire.lastCompletedStep'. But in this row we dont have the information of the keys we need because in the first row we have None.

Comment: You can hard code an `if statement` stating if there is a `None` then `df["questionaire.step"].insert=None
df["questionaire.lastCompletedStep"].insert=None`
you are just preprocessing the data and you know what is there in it so you dont have write a perfectly automated code to do it to filter the dataset unless you are building a pipeline and you want it to work for any type of input

Comment: Exactly, that's the big issue! i wonder if i have to stock and del all row with None value and after split the columns, add them with None value? Or maybe there is another way?